# Standard method to clear the output in C?

Tags: c

I want to clear the output of my program in C (on terminal/console). I see that most website just use `system("cls")` (Windows) or `system("clear")` (Linux), but it's not standard and also platform dependant. How can I accomplish that with standard C?

Comment: There's nothing in standard C to clear the screen.

Comment: `for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) putchar( '\n');` should do... Don't use this on a hardcopy terminal, though... (Tough job, clearing hardcopy terminal "displays"...)

Comment: "In standard C", there is no guarantee that a terminal window exists in the first place.

Comment: Clearing an "output" is a question of the specific output device. Are you talking about a terminal? If so, which one? Additionally, this is completely independent of the programming language. The final line is, your question asks the wrong thing. Please clarify.

Comment: @thebusybee well, some (old?) languages provided a standard command to clear the screen, like the CLS in basic...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Such an exception is not a _standard_, it is a specific language on a specific platform. Not all BASIC implementations provide `CLS`. Compared with C, you would need to add, for example, ncurses to C. "Exceptions approve the rule." ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See [description of the ANSI clear screen commands here](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html)

There are a lot of different ways to use ANSI characters.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("\033[2J");
return 0;
}
```

Another answer [Clearing the screen by printing a character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774983/clearing-the-screen-by-printing-a-character). Covers a variety of other ANSI codes, see examples there.

[How to judge whether stdout supports ANSI escape code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234860/how-to-judge-whether-stdout-supports-ansi-escape-code) is an answer that discusses the ANSI supported terminal in the year 2021 and a method for testing for ANSI support.

Comment: This is also not particularly portable, as it relies on the terminal supporting ANSI escape codes.

Comment: Fair point, added a link to answer about how to tell if terminal supports ANSI.

Comment: Worth mentioning the variants `0` and `1`  (cursor to top and up to cursor) and the `K` escape (clear line).

Comment: agree, lots of ANSI codes available, years ago we used ANSI codes to make an asteroids game on an wyse terminal and 8088 8 bit micro, those were the days!

Comment: Does this work in windows?

Comment: Maybe, depends on which version. See how and what is supported on their site [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).